# How do I pass data to a view in django?

Tags: django

I want to show different page for different device, such as PC and mobile.  Is there any way to tell the user-agent in request, and pass the result(the type of device) to the corresponding view? I don't want to differentiate between them in each view.
what i can find is subclass the View class and override the dispatch method. tell the type of access device in the dispath method and save the result as a attribute of the class, so in get and post method i can get it by self.result.

Comment: Unless you have some major differences between the pages (that are not just different styling/css files and that require actual work on the server-side), usually the solution would be client-sided (javascript and such)

Answer (score 0):

If the distinction you're trying to make can be made using the user agent information as you allude to, this behavior is built in to class based views. The `request` object is saved as `self.request` during the `view` method on the core `View` class, which is called even before `dispatch`, so in `get` and `post` you can check `self.request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')` or any other useful HTTP header.

You're dependent on what information the HTTP request provided, of course.